# syntax error in alter table for ms access for adding column after a column

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, ms-access, syntax

i want to add a new column after a specific column in ms access database . i used the following query :

```
ALTER TABLE tblName DOUBLE ADD newCol AFTER oldCol
```

it gives following error

> Syntax error in ALTER TABLE statement

please help .. im stuck here for a while

Comment: MS Access doesn't support `AFTER`.

Comment: oh.. thanks for the quick reply.. is there any work around

Comment: Create a new table with the columns in the order you want and insert data into them.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Adding a column at a specific location is not important because you can easily change the order of displaying in `SELECT` statement.

There is a very useful post by Pinal Dave you can find it here.

[How to Add Column at Specific Location in Table](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/03/11/sql-server-how-to-add-column-at-specific-location-in-table/)

Comment: In what way is the SQL Server link relevant to MS Access?

Comment: In a way which both using SQL.

Comment: SQL Server SQL and MS Access SQL are often quite different. As are Oracle SQL, MySQL etc ...

Comment: True but the link I mentioned in my answer is trying to talk about SELECT statement which is the same in all SQL databases.

Comment: The description *How to Add Column at Specific Location in Table* is very misleading. Select is not quite the same, although the link SQL is quite simple so it mostly would work as long as you left out GO. MS Access requires specific JOINS (eg INNER JOIN) and a lot of parentheses.